# VBA Workbook_Open() doesn't always work

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this simple VBA code when opening excel workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("HideRibbon")
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False

End Sub
```

However, this works 50% of times and I'm still wondering why. In one of the sheet there is conditional formatting that I have to keep for reporting purposes). I have tried many solutions suggested in this community but they didn't work at all.
Can somebody help me to figure it out?
Many thanks

Comment: So please show *what* you have tried so far. Otherwise people start suggesting the many solutions you already tried. This just wastes both our and your time. • Please clarify if you say *"works 50%"*. Does `Workbook_Open` run at all? Or are just the commands in `Workbook_Open` not doing what you expect? Eg. test this by adding a `msgbox "open run"` before `End Sub`.

Comment: I added the `msgbox command` and it is always displayed. When I say that macro runs 50% of time means that the rest of the code doesn't run at all half of the time and only sometimes it shows an error 91 message corresponding to the following line: `ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False`.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue that the application isn't ready when the code runs. Try to add `Do While Not Application.Ready: DoEvents: Loop` as first line to wait until the application is ready.

Comment: Apparently I solved the problem by using the following code: `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
   Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
End Sub`
However, this code affects also other workbooks that I opened at the same time when I open the relevant workbook in consideration. How can I write VBA in order to make the code affecting only the relevant workbook (called 'UserForm Trial")?